# How do I run a remote node on windows (so I can connect mobile wallets to my own node)

Tags: full-node, windows, mobile

I couldn't find a detailed answer specifically for Windows users.  What is the simplest way to get a Windows 10 full node able to accept a connection from a mobile wallet so I can connect to a node I am in control of?

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the Monero files to monero folder in C:

Right click on monerod and create a shortcut.

Right click on monerod.exe -shortcut and open "properties"

In the "target" field put in C:\monero\monerod.exe --rpc-bind-ip 192.168.1.100 --confirm-external-bind --restricted-rpc

In your router you will need to forward ports 18080 and 18081 to the IP of your machine running monerod.

I am unsure if there are any benefits to setting a password.

In addition, I made a task in task scheduler to start monerod at bootup (with the same options --rpc-bind-ip 192.168.1.100 --confirm-external-bind --restricted-rpc), and set my PC bios to automatically boot in case of power outage, this way its always running.

Comment: Find your WAN IP (ipchicken.com) and you can add it to your mobile wallet (cakewallet or monerujo) remote node list and use port 18081.